# How to add ?nl! at the end of link which is in specific div?

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, href

On the page there are many divs with class=field-content.I am trying to add ?nl! at the end of each link wchich is div:field-content. Here is the jquery however it doesnt work.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     var $this = $('.field-content');       
     var _href = $this.attr("href"); 
     $this.attr("href", _href + '?nl!');


  });






   <div class="field-content" >    
    <a href="/content/electro">
<img src="xxx" alt="" height="70" width="200">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are the hrefs of all divs identical?

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting the parent `<div>`  not the `<a>` and not iterating instances

Use [`attr(attrName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) which will loop over the collection and return updated value for each instance

```
$('.field-content > a').attr("href", function(_, _href){    
   return _href + '?nl!';
});
```

Comment: Amazing! I didn't know that was possible.